# Группировка строк PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Прошу помочь с вопросом ниже:

У меня есть две таблицы

```
1.

|plan_item_id|
|------------| 
|id1         |
|id2         |
|id3         |

2.

|plan_item_id|name_ru|
|------------|-------| 
|id1         |A      |
|id1         |B      |
|id2         |C      |
|id2         |D      |
|id3         |E      |
```

Я хочу эти две таблицы связать и показать в итоге:

- id1 A,B
- id2 C,D
- id3 E

Как это сделать, буду очень признателен за подсказку

Comment: `GROUP BY` + [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Первая таблица нам не понадобится для решения задачи.

```
SELECT
   plan_item_id,
   STRING_AGG(name_ru,',') name_ru_list
GROUP BY
   plan_item_id
ORDER BY
   plan_item_id
```

Comment: возможно первая таблица нужна для фильтрации с `inner join`

Comment: @teran, ну как вариант